# Display: inline-block will not work with PHP (screenshots included)

Tags: php, html, css, sql

I'm currently creating an e-commerce site. I'm using PHP/SQL to display information on the product.

I have set a display: inline-block in the CSS and it seems to work fine when there is no PHP. However once I put in the php, it seems like it becomes a display: block element instead.

Here is my code for the html/php:

```
<section class="products">

    <div class="sectionintro introcontainer">
     <h1>Gucci</h1>
     <p>Established in Florence in 1921, Gucci has evolved from a manufacturer of quality leather accessories into one of the world’s premiere luxury brands. A legacy of glamour, elegance, and modernity underpin its status as a bastion of essential Italian fashion. Alessandro Michele, named creative director in 2015, has ushered in a uniquely contemporary vision of luxury with his eclectic, bohemian, and highly romantic designs. </p>
    </div>



        <article>

        <?php

 $query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_brand = 'Gucci' ";

 $select_all_products = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_products)){

    $product_id = $row['product_id'];
    $product_name = $row['product_name'];
    $product_type = $row['product_type'];
    $product_image_front = $row['product_image_front'];
    $product_image_back = $row['product_image_back'];
    $product_image_side = $row['product_image_side'];
    $product_image_full = $row['product_image_full'];
    $product_description = $row['product_description'];
    $product_price = $row['product_price'];
    $product_brand = $row['product_brand'];

?>

        <img  src="productImages/<?php echo $product_image_front ?>" >
         <h2><?php echo $product_brand; ?></h2>
          <h3><?php echo $product_name; ?></h3>
          <p><?php echo $product_price; ?></p>
<?php } ?>
</article>
</section>
```

here is a screenshot of what happens:

[image]

and here is my CSS:

```
.products article{
    display:inline-block;
    width:33%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom:60px;
    padding-top:20px;
}
```

Here is what happens when there's no PHP:

[image]

What am I doing wrong in my code?

Comment: The styling doesn't depend on the scripting language that you are using it depends on your markup. There must be something wrong in your code. Try to inspect the code in firefox and you will get where exactly your markup is breaking.

Comment: @aavrug before I even put the PHP the inline-block was working perfectly fine, like in the second screenshot...maybe I'm placing the PHP in the wrong place or something?

Comment: Did you followed what I said.

Comment: You need to but the `<article>`-tags inside the loop. Right now, you're only having one `<article>`-tag (which is what you set the `inline-block` on) where you put all the products in.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Nice catch.

Comment: @aavrug  
I've inspected it, it still says the display:inline-block is there. I have tried to modify things when I'm inspecting the code but right now I have no luc

Comment: @ThierryDiallo see Magnus gave the answer.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson let me try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the `inline-block` on the `<article>`-tag, which means that you need to put the `<article>`-tag *inside* the loop:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_brand = 'Gucci' ";
$select_all_products = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_products)){

    $product_id = $row['product_id'];
    $product_name = $row['product_name'];
    $product_type = $row['product_type'];
    $product_image_front = $row['product_image_front'];
    $product_image_back = $row['product_image_back'];
    $product_image_side = $row['product_image_side'];
    $product_image_full = $row['product_image_full'];
    $product_description = $row['product_description'];
    $product_price = $row['product_price'];
    $product_brand = $row['product_brand'];
?>

    <article>
        <img src="productImages/<?php echo $product_image_front ?>" />
        <h2><?php echo $product_brand; ?></h2>
        <h3><?php echo $product_name; ?></h3>
        <p><?php echo $product_price; ?></p>
    </article>

<?php } ?>
```

Currently, you're putting all products in the same (and only) `<article>`-tag.